# multiple xmlhttp requests with javascript asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I have an array of movie titles for which I'm retrieving meta data via xmlhttp requests. I'd like to just use javascript to keep this a light as possible as it will run on mobile. When I do this asynchronously I'm getting 10 of the same objects, which is my last search url in the array. It works fine if I set async to false, but obviously this is not desirable. Here's the parts of my code related to this issue...

```
var movieObjArr = [];
var searchUrls = [
    // 10 search urls

];

function fetchMovieData(searchUrl) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          var result = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
          response(result);
      }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", searchUrl, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function response(result){
    movieObj.push(result);

    // once the movieObjArr has ALL the search results, display them
    // I must wait until all results are in because I then sort the array 
       so it's in alphabetical order
    if (movieObjArr.length == searchUrls.length){
        // call sort function
        // go through movieObjArr and display each result
    }
}
```

Code as it is displays:

last search result
last search result
last search result... 10 times

If I change async to false, it displays correctly:
1st search result
2nd search result... and so on

Comment: If you were using `jQuery` this could have been solved easily by using `promise`s objects and `$.when` but as you said no library so you need to use the plain javascript [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object and do the trick..

Comment: ahh ok didn't think of promises... it seems to be working now. If you'd like to post something in answer form, I'm good with that as it lead me to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using jQuery [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) this could have been solved easily by using `promise`s objects and [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) but as you said no library and also considering the mobiles, so you need to use the plain javascript [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object which has support in ECMAScript 6.